# AssertCalled always fails with testify library

Tags: go, testify

I am using testify to test my code and I want to check if a function was called.

I am doing the following:

```
type Foo struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m Foo) Bar() {

}

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    m := Foo{}
    m.Bar()
    m.AssertCalled(t, "Bar")
}
```

The error I am getting:

```
Error:      Should be true
Messages:   The "Bar" method should have been called with 0 argument(s), but was not.

mock.go:419: []
```

I call function "Bar" and immediately ask if it was called but it returns false.
What am I doing wrong?
What is the proper way to test if a function was called with testify?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tried with this and works:

```
type Foo struct {                                                                                                                                                    
    mock.Mock                                                                                                                                                          
}                                                                                                                                                                    

func (m *Foo) Bar() {                                                                                                                                                
    m.Called()                                                                                                                                                         
}                                                                                                                                                                    

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {                                                                                                                                         
    m := &Foo{}                                                                                                                                                        
    m.On("Bar").Return(nil)                                                                                                                                            

    m.Bar()                                                                                                                                                            
    m.AssertCalled(t, "Bar")                                                                                                                                           
}
```

As stated by **Chris Drew**, you've to use a receiver pointer on *Bar* method's declaration.

Additionally, you've to istantiate a new structure as pointer and mock the method to return a value.

Comment: Thanks, I replied on GitHub too :)

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [documentation of testify](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/mock#Mock.Called) I think you have to explicitly call `func (*Mock) Called` to tell the mock object that a method has been called.

```
func (m *Foo) Bar() {
    m.Called()
}
```

There are [some examples](https://github.com/stretchr/testify/blob/master/mock/mock_test.go) in the testify tests.

Comment: I tried that before posting but it just generates the following error: "assert: mock: I don't know what to return because the method call was unexpected."

Comment: I think that might be because your method takes the receiver by value so only a copy of the mock is being updated. Try using a pointer receiver. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it is pointer receiver NOT value receiver.

This will always have **nil Calls**

```
type Foo struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m Foo) Bar() 
    m.Called()
}
```

This will have **N number of Calls**

```
type Foo struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m *Foo) Bar() 
    m.Called()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an additional solution for when you want/need to use a value receiver, though not as clean, specifying Mock as a pointer field worked for me.

```
type Foo struct {
    m *mock.Mock
}

func (f Foo) Bar() {
    f.m.Called()
}

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    f := Foo{m: &mock.Mock{}}
    f.Bar()
    f.m.AssertCalled(t, "Bar")
}
```